# Calling OnServerClick from iframe Not Working

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net, html, iframe

I have a vb.net server side function that I need to call from an iframe.

The function is as follows:

```
  Sub ChangeView(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)


    If MultiView1.ActiveViewIndex = 0 Then
        MultiView1.SetActiveView(View2)
    ElseIf MultiView1.ActiveViewIndex = 1 Then
        MultiView1.SetActiveView(View3)
    ElseIf MultiView1.ActiveViewIndex = 2 Then
        MultiView1.SetActiveView(View1)
    End If
  End Sub
```

The body containing the multiview and iframe:

```
<body>

   <form id="form1" runat="server">
       <asp:ScriptManager ID="SM1" runat="server" />
  <iframe src="Page/index.html" width="100%" height="650px" scrolling="no" frameborder="0"></iframe>
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UP1" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>

     <asp:MultiView ID="MultiView1" runat="server" ActiveViewIndex="0">
        <asp:View ID="View1" runat="server">
            This is View1.
        </asp:View>
        <asp:View ID="View2" runat="server">
            This is View2.
        </asp:View>
        <asp:View ID="View3" runat="server">
            This is View3.
        </asp:View>
    </asp:MultiView>




       </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
   </form>

</body>
```

The iframe source:

```
<nav>
  <ul id="nav">
    <li><a  onserverclick="ChangeView" runat="server">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">About</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Message</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Mission, Visions, Goals</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Disclaimer: I've been working on this for three days, simple as it may be, I'm struggling with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, not moved to .net 4.5 yet so not familiar with onserverclick ... but you are calling ChangeView by clicking a hyperlink in an iframe - and expecting a function in the page containing the iframe to be called?

Within your iframe page, does the code compile? Can it 'see' the MultiView1 control on the parent page? I would expect that when you click the hyperlink within the iframe you would have to run a bit of javascript along the lines of:

```
window.parent.document.getElementById('somebutton').click();
```

and have an invisible button on the parent page whose click event calls ChangeView();

Comment: You're right, the problem is within iframe, it doesn't compile the javascript at all. Perhaps I'm missing something fundamental? (I'm only an apprentice in asp.net)

Comment: Hi. It appears onclick event only takes a line of code. Thanks for your help! I was wondering if you know how to pass a parameter to the button, which will be sent afterwards for server side operations?